# Почему при делении результат округляется?

Tags: java

Не могу понять почему у меня в примере ниже результат округляется (ответ 0.0, а не 0.1)

```
public static double addTenPercent(int i) {
    double x = i/100;
    return x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(addTenPercent(10));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что при целочисленном деление результат округляется вниз к целому числу. Нужно написать `double(i)/100` или `i/100.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы java не округляла результат при делении нужно указать это перед выражением сигнатурой - (double):

```
public static double division(int a, int b) {
    double x = (double) a / b; //деление
    return x;
}

public static double percent(int a, int b) {
    double x = (double) a * b / 100; //процент от числа
    return x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет не double(i)/100, a (double)i/100
A по задаче неправильно так писать функцию, надо так:

```
public static double addIntPercent(double x, int i) {
    double result = x + x*i/100.0; 
    return result;
}

public static double addTenPercent(double x) {
    return addIntPercent(x,10);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(addTenPercent(342.5,10));
}
```