# Вывод текста в цикле else.Java

Tags: java, if

При создании маленького консольного калькулятора

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        int str4 = str.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        Scanner str2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int str5 = str2.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Choose:");
        System.out.println("1 - sum \n2 - minus \n3 - devided by \n4 - times");
        Scanner str3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int str6 = str3.nextInt();
        if(str6 == 1){
            System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 + str5));
        }
        if(str6 == 2){
            System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 - str5));
        }
        if(str6 == 3){
            System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 / str5));
        }
        if(str6 == 4){
            System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 * str5));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
```

После каждого расчета выводится на экран Error! если указать правильные данные:

```
Enter first number
1
Enter second number
2
Choose:
1 - sum 
2 - minus 
3 - devided by 
4 - times
3
Result: 0
Error!
```

1)Как это сделать что бы не выводился Error?2)Почему выводится данный Error?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java.Почему в c записывается только целая часть?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569101/java-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: + [Почему при делении результат округляется?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534685/191482) и т.д. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20

Comment: Проблема в том, что этот `else` относится только к последней проверке `if(str6 == 4)`. Так как Вы ввели тройку, последняя проверка оказывается ложной и выполняется тело оператора `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Используйте switch case!**

Не понимаю, зачем вы несколько раз создаете новый объект Scanner...

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final String RESULT = "Result: ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int str4 = read("Enter first number");
        int str5 = read("Enter second number");
        System.out.println("Choose:");
        int str6 = read("1 - sum \n2 - minus \n3 - devided by \n4 - times");
        switch(str6){
            case 1:
               System.out.println(RESULT + (str4 + str5));
               break;
            case 2:
               System.out.println(RESULT + (str4 - str5));
               break;
            case 3:
               Double d = (double) str4 / str5;
               System.out.println(RESULT + d);
               break;
            case 4:
               System.out.println(RESULT + (str4 * str5));
               break;
            default:
               System.out.println("Error!");
               break;
        }
    }

    private static int read(String s) {
      System.out.println(s);
      return str.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного улучшил ваш код

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
    if(str6 == 1){
        System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 + str5));
    }
    else if(str6 == 2){
        System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 - str5));
    }
    else if(str6 == 3){
        System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 / str5));
    }
    else if(str6 == 4){
        System.out.println("Result: "  + (str4 * str5));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
```