# Java: Проверка на простое число

Tags: java, деление

Пытаюсь написать программу для проверки числа на простое путем циклов и дальнейшим принтом делителей если число не простое.

Но мне просто распечатываются все числа до моего числа (в данном случае: ...948,949,950,951).

Подскажите пожалуйста, что тут нужно исправить?

```
public class FP {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 951;
        int i, c;
        double b;
        for(i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            b = a / i;
            if (b%1 == 0)
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (b%1 == 0)` ?? попробуйте объяснить словами, что тут делается

Comment: @Igor в java взятие остатка для чисел с плавающей точкой определено так, что это выражение действительно даст дробную часть  ([jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему при делении результат округляется?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534685/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

Comment: @zRrr Очень интересно, спасибо. Разве у результата `a / i` будет дробная часть?

Answer (score 1):

а почему не до корня

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= a; ++i) {
    if (a % i == 0) {
        //не простое
    }
}
```

если не напечает то простое

Comment: а почему не двойка и нечетные числа?

Comment: @Igor не очень понял вопрос

Comment: на 4, 6 и т.д. нет же смысла делить

Comment: @Igor ну это общий алгоритм. я понимаю что 4=2*2, 6=2*3... Но тонда и на 9 и 12 и тд нет смысла делить. можешь сделать массив простых чисел и делить только на них

Comment: @Igor Можете попробовать посмотреть, что такое решето Эратомфена, тоже хороший алгоритм